# Visual Studio Refacotring to match physical file name and class name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

the physical file names of my VS2010 C# project do not match the class or interface name in the source code, but it is always good to make them have the same name... 
So is there a way in VS2010 Pro or in Resharper that I can say hey rename file names to match with their class or interface name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes - with ReSharper:

1) just set cursor on the class name and push Alt+Enter - you'll see this option.

[image]

2) right click on the file -> Refactor -> Move Types Into Matching Files...

You can select several files from solution to run this refactoring.

**Or if you want to do this for the whole solution - right click on the solution file and you'll see this option as well.**

[image]